# Is it possible to configure "wine" in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, wine

I'm new to heroku, I have an application deployed in heroku, this application needs to run some ".exe" to work perfectly.
Is it possible to configure "wine" in heroku to open these files? If possible, what is the procedure to be done?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about that, but you can use the Docker deployment in heroku combined with the wine instalation inside the Docker image.

Heroku Docker Deployment:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Docker image with a wine installation:
https://hub.docker.com/r/suchja/wine/

Hope it helps.